# SPARK: unpersist a big RDD after another RDD is fully in memory

Tags: memory, apache-spark, persist

I want to unpersist an RDD (RDD1) after another RDD (RDD2) is fully in memory. I have the following code:

```
val RDD2 = MyProcessor.process(RDD1).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER_2).
  setName("RDD2")

if (RDD2.count > 0) {
  RDD1.unpersist()
}
```

However, RDD2.count becomes very slow with big dataset. Is there a better way can ensure that RDD1 will unpersist after RDD2 is fully in memory?

Thanks!

Comment: In your program, Are you using some other actions after this code ?

Answer (score 0):

Making a count over the RDD2 is a very expensive operation in your case. You cannot directly check if the RDD2 is fully loaded inside the main memory. You have to run first an action (as you did) on the RDD2 and then Spark will persist the RDD2 for subsequent iterations. However, the above approach is not totally efficient since you have to perform a whole scan over the RDD2 and if the RDD1 and RDD2 together are close to exceed your available memory then your execution time will be much slower.

Two alternative suggestions to check if the size of RDD2 is greater than 0 are:

1. check if the RDD is not empty (!RDD.isEmpty)
2. check if at least one element exists (!RDD.take(1)==0 or !RDD.first()==0)

Comment: I tried RDD2.isEmpty before. However, it unpersist() RDD1 before it put the entire RDD2 in memory, making things slow. Any more thoughts?

Comment: I cannot think of something very efficient because the .cache() and .persist() are lazy operations and you need an action to start loading the whole RDD2 into memory. My suggestion is to apply a reduce(func) instead of count() on the RDD2 before the RDD1.unpersist() so that you could minimize the computation time needed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you caching RDD1 exclusively to speed up `MyProcessor.process(RDD1)`? Do you perform any transformations and actions on RDD1 after caching and before the call to `MyProcessor.process(RDD1)`? These are things you might have to revisit because `cache` is lazy, so if in `MyProcessor.process(RDD1)` you only ever perform a single action on RDD1 then `unpersist` it afterwards then I don't think you'd be making the most of caching.